# Ajax doesn't send variables to PHP by POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need to send only 1 variable to my .php file using AJAX (using method POST) and show it (with php). Here is my HTML code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
            var XMLHttpRequestObject = false; //LO INICIALIZAMOS A FALSO PARA DESPUES COMPROBAR QUE ESTA CREADO CORRECTAMENTE
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //PARA INTERNET EXPLORER

            }

            function irweb(idDiv) {

                if (XMLHttpRequestObject) {
                    var objeto = document.getElementById(idDiv);
                    nom1="holaaaaaaa";
                  //  var nom1 = document.getElementById('nombre').value;                    
                //var com1 = document.getElementById('comentarios').value;

                    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", "p2.php?");
                    XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
                                XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
                            objeto.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    XMLHttpRequestObject.send("n="+nom1);
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  method="post" id="formulario">

            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick ="irweb('contenedor')" id="enviar"/>
        </form>
        <div id="contenedor" style="background-color:#99FF66;text-align:center;"></div>        
    </body>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$cabe = <<< 'EOD'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
<head>
</head>
<html>
<body>  
<p>hola</p>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
$pasado1=$_POST["n"];
$pasado2=$_POST["c"];
echo "El parametro pasado es -->".$pasado1;
echo "El parametro pasado es -->".$pasado2;
?>
```

I called some alerts in the JS code, to chek if I get the values correctly, and it works, but when I call the php file, nothing happens

Comment: You can use FF/Chrome's developer tools to see the request being sent and the content being sent - so it would greatly assist in finding the problem

Comment: '?' is not needed in here:: XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", "p2.php?");..!

Comment: cant you use JQuery for making ajax calls?

Comment: Why does someone have to suggest adding 90k of third-party library to a page every time someone has a trivial problem involving XHR?

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the submit button, you:

- Run the JavaScript
- Submit the form

You don't see a result from the JS because the form submits (reloading the page) before the readystate has reached 4.

Stop the form submitting if the JS runs:

```
onclick="irweb('contenedor'); return false;"
```

… and fix your server side script so it can handle the POST data if the JS fails for any reason and the form does submit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jquery? If not, try it for easy coding and maintenance
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

The ajax post code is simply as below :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```